# How do I get my HP LaserJet 5P working?

Tags: 10.04, hardware, printing, hp

Ubuntu won't detect my HP LaserJet 5P. I'm on 10.04. Tried for hours to get printer to work.

Is there somewhere a software that says detect hardware? Do I need a software add-on to get it recognized?

Got HPLIP to install. I had to update something to do with the software center. Did that & then it let me download the HPLIP. It found my p2015 printer, but not my p5.

Comment: which printer plz update your ? , name with model no

Comment: hp laser jet 5p

Answer (score 1):

Your printer is [listed](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_5p.html) as supported by HP. Ensure you have [hplip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/hplip) [image: Install hplip] installed.

After you install it you should then see an HP Printer tool in your menu that you can use to configure your printer. Please edit your question with what happens when you try that.

Comment: I downloaded this hplip. I have no idea on how to install it. I get a device URI message in the add a printer. How do I get that?

Comment: @mrccim Don't download it from there, click on the link in my answer, that should install it for you.

Comment: It says choose an application???

Comment: @Mrccim Ok try launching the software center, and then searching for "hplip" in there, and installing it.

Comment: Went to software center, found the file, hit installed, then got this message: requires installation of untrusted software. The download stopped after that....I do appreciate your help here. I can see why it's a Windows world.....

Comment: Got HPLIP to install. I had to update something to do with the software center. Did that & then it let me download the HPLIP. It found my p2015 printer, but not my p5.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a HP printer, open HPLIP Toolbox from the menu (it should be installed by default IIRC, if it is not, find HPLIP in the software center and install it).

It will usually find your printer automatically, but if it does not:

Click on the + button
[image: HPLIP Toolbox]

This will give you a "wizard" to find your printer if it is not detected automatically. Then, all you need to do is walk through the steps, and your printer will be added to the system and ready for printing.

Comment: Downloaded this HPLIP, can't figure out how to install it.

Comment: @Mrccim: Clearly, you didn't follow the instructions correctly. I said to install it from the software center.